# Unwrap <img> tag and move <a> tag to another <img>

Tags: jquery

I have an Image with an Link. This is my Markup:

```
<figure>
   <a href="index.php/home.html">
      <img src="300x380.png" width="300" height="380" alt="">
   </a>
</figure>
```

Now, i need the Link at another position, but how?

```
<a href="index.php/home.html">
    <img src="otherimg.png">
</a>

<figure>
       <img src="300x380.png" width="300" height="380" alt="">
</figure>
```

This is my jQuery, but only the unwrap Part.

```
$('figure a img').unwrap('<a>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('figure').each(function () {
    var myFigure = $(this);
    var myAnchor = $(myFigure).find('a');
    var myImage  = $(myAnchor).find('img');
    var newImage = '<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" alt="" />';

    $(myFigure).append(myImage).before(myAnchor);
    $(myAnchor).html(newImage);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/db63f0zh

The `each()` function may not be needed, but it'll cover more scenarios.

Comment: great, thanks. but is it also possible to wrap the link to an div?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but look into `wrap()`.

Comment: yes, it is wrap()!
but i have another problem, i have 10 <figure> Tags in my Code, and the script add to every Tag an new Image..how can i fix it? here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/db63f0zh/36/

Comment: What's supposed to happen? Where is the new image URL coming from? Might be best to open a new question and include that information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var aTag = ($('figure').children('a')).clone();
var newTag = $(aTag).children('img').attr('src','otherimg.png');
$('figure').parent().append(newTag);
$('figure a img').unwrap('<a>');
```

Working [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/efbu0bqd/)

Comment: Where is the same image?

Comment: I was mistaken. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

No unwrap needed -

```
var originalImg = $('figure > a').html();
$('figure > a').prependTo('body').html('<img src="http://placehold.it/200x280">'); // this moves the a tag and then adds the other image info to it
$(originalImg).appendTo('figure');
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/ysnwaxLm/1/